# How to use click in Selenium for opening links

Tags: python, selenium

I am having trouble with Selenium lately.
I'm trying to get all the URL from

> http://cimex.co/resources.html

and open it on a new tab.

I'm trying to achieve with this code:

```
import selenium, os
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://cimex.co/resources.html')
links = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('a[href^="https"]')
links[0].click()
```

While I am facing another problem is there any chance if it detects Firefox running just open the URL in a new tab rather than opening Firefox as a new app.

Thanks.
Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 1):

I already had to do that, it was with the ChromeDriver, I cannot say if it will works the same with Firefox, but here is the code:

```
def Browser(object):

   def __init__(self):
       self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
       self._tabs = {'default': self.driver.window_handles[0]}


    def new_tab(self, name):
        '''
        Create new tab `name`.
            name    New tab name
        '''
        self.driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 't')
        self._tabs[name] = self.driver.window_handles[-1]


    def switch_tab(self, name):
        '''
        Switch to given tab.
            name    Tab name to switch
        '''
        self.driver.switch_to_window(self._tabs[name])


browser = Browser()
browser.driver.get('http://cimex.co/resources.html')

links = browser.driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('a[href^="https"]')
url = links[0].get_attribute('href')

# open new tab
browser.new_tab(url, 'tab-name')
# switch to new tab
browser.switch_tab('tab-name')
# back to default tab
browser.switch_tab('default')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = r'D:/Automation/geckodriver.exe')
browser.get("http://cimex.co/resources.html")

wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 30) 
main_tab = browser.current_window_handle
print(main_tab)
links = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')

size = len(links)
print ('this the length of list:',size)
i = 0 
while i<size:
 ActionChains(browser).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).click(links[i]).key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform() 
 browser.switch_to_window(main_tab)
 i=i+1;
 if i >= size:
  break

print(" here you quit the driver as per your wish")
```

Answer (score -1):

from selenium import webdriver

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox(gecko driver location)

browser.get('http://cimex.co/resources.html')

links = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('a[href^="https"]')

for link in links:

    link.click()
```

Comment: Note that after first click , driver will have to come to main page to click on 2nd click and so on.